# Must i remove an electric range heating element to test it?

Tags: repair, oven

I have a samsung electric range that is not heating properly for baking.  I removed the back panel and tested the thermostat (0.1 ohms) and the temperature sensor (1.07k ohms), both were within spec.  The heating element had no continuity and so I expect it will need replacement.

I noticed in the manual and also in several articles online [link](https://www.wikihow.com/Test-an-Oven-Element) that it is recommended you remove the element before testing.  I didn't do this.  I simply removed the wires from its terminals and attached my probes to the terminals.

For what it's worth, I tested the broiler element (it works) the same way and got a reading of 16 ohms.

Why does it say to remove the element if it seems like you can test it right in its place?

Comment: Unless there is some connection with it in place, then just removing the connections should be okay.  Seeing a replacement might be needed anyway, testing again when it is removed won't hurt before buying a new one.

Comment: Based on watching videos of people removing the element, the only connections are the two wires I removed.  The replacement is on its way and I guess it wouldn't hurt to test this again once I have started the repair and before I open the package on the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Since your testing the element, makes sense to isolate it. I've had more connectors to the element go bad than actual elements. There are usually only two screws to attach the elements to the oven and when you remove those and pull the element out, you can inspect the connectors and the element and do your testing without moving out the range.

Comment: if I have already tested directly on the element itself and read no continuity,  is there any way that the element could still be good?  Regardless of the condition of the connectors, the element is dead.  Removing it shouldn't have made a difference

Comment: @nuggethead    If there's no continuity, then the element's dead... end of story. In your case everything worked out great. If a connector had failed though, you'd have no continuity testing it the way you did and then you'd be getting a new element that wasn't needed. Removing the element answers both problems.